# View created folder in internal storage android

Tags: android, storage

I used the code below to create a file in internal storage.

```
    ContextWrapper contextWrapper = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
    File directory = contextWrapper.getDir(filepath, 0);
    File myInternalFile = new File(directory , "MySampleFile.txt");
    //for writing
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(myInternalFile);
        fos.write("data".toString().getBytes());
        fos.close();
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //for reading
    String myData="";
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myInternalFile);
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fis);
        BufferedReader br =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String strLine;
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            myData = myData + strLine;
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), myData, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//prints data
```

I am able to read and write to the file.
what i want to know is how can i browse to the file or view the file?
used file explorer but did't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot

```
myInternalFile.createNewFile();
```

**UPD** I got your question. From [doc](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html) `ContextWrapper.getDir` :

> Retrieve, creating if needed, a new directory in which the application can place its own custom data files. You can use the
>   returned File object to create and access files in this directory.
>   Note that files created through a File object will only be accessible
>   by your own application; you can only set the mode of the entire
>   directory, not of individual files.

So only your app can access that folder. Probably it possible reach it on rooted devices. In order to get path of file just print it in log or check in debug mode.

Comment: i am able to read and write to the file but could't find its location

Comment: i am planning to store images in that folder and want to browse it later.what should i do?

Comment: You shouldn't store it in that folder, but should use external storage. All information could be found here - http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: ya got your point :) but i have seen some apps in which, when they are installed, a folder with the package name is created in internal storage and the user used images are stored there.And i could access it with file manager. How do they do it?

Comment: You can't see internal storage. Seems you are misunderstanding what internal and what's external storage is - please read my link above carefully.